# Inequality about functions of bounded variation and Riemann-Stieltjes integrals

Tags: definite-integrals, bounded-variation, stieltjes-integral

Let $\alpha$ be a functions of bounded variations on $[a, b]$ and $f$ a buonded function such that $f \in R(\alpha)$ (i.e. integrable with $\alpha$ as integrator).$V(x)$ is the total variation of $\alpha$ in $[a, x]$ with $V(a)=0$.

I need to prove that

\begin{gather*} 
\left| \ \int_a^b f \ d \alpha \ \right| \leq \int_a^b \mid f \mid  \ d V
\end{gather*}

**What I've tried**

$D=V-\alpha$, then $V$ and $D$ are increasing functions and we can write:

\begin{gather*} 
\int_a^b f \ d \alpha = \int_a^b f \ d V - \int_a^b f \ d D \leq \int_a^b \mid f \mid  \ d V  - \int_a^b f \ d D
\end{gather*}

I think I need some considerations on the link between the signs of $V$ and $D$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that if $f \in \mathcal{R}(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is of bounded variation , then $f$ is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to both the increasing functions $V$ and $D = V- \alpha$ as you claim.  The function $D$ is not needed for this proof.

Take $g = (V+\alpha)/2$ and $h = (V-\alpha)/2$.  Both $g$ and $h$ are increasing functions and, as linear combinations of $V$ and $\alpha$, it follows that $f$ is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to these integrators. Thus,

$$\tag{1}\left|\int_a^b f \, d\alpha\right| = \left|\int_a^b f \, d(g-h)\right| =  \left|\int_a^b f \, dg - \int_a^b f \, dh\right| \leqslant  \left|\int_a^b f \, dg \right|+  \left| \int_a^b f \, dh\right|$$

Since $g$ and $h$ are increasing we have $\left|\int_a^b f \, dg \right|\leqslant \int_a^b |f| \, dg $ and $\left|\int_a^b f \, dh \right|\leqslant \int_a^b |f| \, dh $, and, substituting into (1), it follows that

$$\tag{2}\left|\int_a^b f \, d\alpha \right| \leqslant \int_a^b |f| \, dg + \int_a^b |f| \, dh = \int_a^b |f| \, d(g+h) $$

Since $V = g+h$, we get upon substitution into (2)

$$\left|\int_a^b f \, d\alpha \right| \leqslant \int_a^b |f| \, dV $$

Comment: Thank you very much. There is a step i don't get: $g$ is increasing. For $h$ the following is enough: $V - \alpha$ is increasing infact for $y \ge x$ we have $V(y)-V(x) \ge \alpha(y) - \alpha(x)$ from the definition of total variation.

Comment: @GiovanniBarbarani: Also for $y \geqslant x$ we have $V(y) - V(x) \geqslant |\alpha(y) - \alpha(x)| \geqslant \alpha(x) - \alpha(y) \implies V(y) + \alpha(y) \geqslant V(x) + \alpha(x)$

Comment: Ok, I got it. If $\alpha$ is of bounded variation also $-\alpha$ is of bounded variation. Now from the absolute value in the definition of total variation we have that the total variation of $\alpha$ and $-\alpha$ are equals and $V + \alpha$ is increasing. :)

Comment: The proof in your comment is more appropriate and come directly from the definition, thanks. (I was trying to combine some lemmas that I had on hand in a cumbersome way).