# Bounds on Integral $\int_{0}^{t}\sin(2\pi\omega \tau)d\eta(\tau)$, where the function $\eta(\tau)$ is of bounded variation

Tags: fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, stieltjes-integral

I am trying to find an upper bound on the integral: $$\int_{0}^{t}\sin(2\pi\omega \tau)~d\eta(\tau),$$ where the function $\eta(\cdot)$ is continuous and of bounded variation, hopefully in terms of the total variation of the function $\eta(\cdot)$ divided by the frequency $\omega$.

Comment: This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3663561/148510) shows how to bound Riemann-Stieltjes integral with another integral that has the total variation as the integrator.